# How to store nested key-value-pairs with moneta

Tags: ruby

I'm wondering how I could store nested key-value-pairs with the rubygem *moneta*. I tried out that one:

```
store = Moneta.new(:YAML,:file => 'data.yaml')
store['key']['nestedKey'] = 'value'
store.close
```

but I recieved this error message:

```
moneta-test.rb:5:in `[]=': string not matched (IndexError)
        from moneta-test.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

I have absolutely no clue how to achieve this.

EDIT: at least my YAML-file should look like this:

```
key:
    nestedKey: 'Value'
    anotherKey: 'anotherValue'
```

Comment: Can you give an example about nested key-value-pairs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seems you can only have one key, but you can store a hash. So, this should be possible:

```
store['key'] = { 'nestedKey' => 'value' }
```